# How to setup https website when I have own CA

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, apache2, windows-server-2019, certificate-authority

I have very interesting question for me... I'm runnig webserver on linux machine (debian 10) with apache. In the same domain I have Windows Server on which are my DNS server and Certificate authority.
Can I setup secured https website on the linux machine? I don't want red error that says "unsecured".

If somebody know, how to setup it tell me that solution.
Thanks

Comment: Create a _certificate signing request_ (CSR) on the Linux Server, issue a certificate on the Windows CA & install it on the Linux Server.

Comment: You should make sure your linux server and all clients are trusting your Windows CA, otherwise it wont work.